# Creating variable out of random output

Tags: python, variables, random

So I'm creating a basic (my first project using python) game with python. there is a part where I put a random.choice. I want to refer back to the same random number that it picked so I wondered if it is possible to create a variable for that output. I've tried str = randomint(1,7) but that didnt give me the result I wanted.

```
# random module
import random
dice1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
print (random.choice(dice1))
```

Comment: Well what is the result you wanted?

Comment: You already have answers, but let me give some different advice: You're making a mistake many beginning programmers make by using strings for everything. Strings are slow and complicated; computers like numbers. Try to train yourself to avoid strings unless they are really necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you would generate and then store a random number in Python. If you want a number between two numbers use [`random.randint(a,b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint). Note that using randint will give you an int and not a string

```
import random
number = random.randint(1,7)
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of random.choice is indeed giving you a random selection from your list dice1. You can store the return value of random.choice in a variable.

```
# random module
import random
dice1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
random_number = random.choice(dice1)
```